# Flutter - how to debug the native android code

Tags: android, flutter

I have been trying to debug the native android code that is invoked through platform channel in flutter and the debugging is only in the flutter side. The execution doesn't hit the breakpoint in the native android. The application is working as expected but the debugging doesn't. I am using Android studio. Can some one please tell me how to debug the native android code ?

Comment: Maybe add the source code so we can help you

Comment: Well if you're using android studio IDE you can open only android module of your app and then you can write and debug your code as a native android app. You can do this with a right click on your project root folder and go to Flutter > Open android module in android studio option.

Comment: When I try that the Flutter option in the drop down is greyed out. And I am using the platform_channels sample example that is in flutter.

Comment: Then try File > Open > yourProjectName > android. In android studio IDE of course.

Comment: Yep I have that and when I try to debug that - it crashes when I try to debug it.

Comment: Weird. Do you have updated versions of you IDE and IDE Flutter plugin? I've never seen this behavior before.

Comment: Yes all the versions are current and the exception I get is 
       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.trial-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.trial-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.trial-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file /data/app/com.trial-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.trial-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"

Comment: And 
W/WindowManager: Failed looking up window
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@9fd07d4 does not exist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189407/discussion-between-shruthi-and-marcos-boaventura).

Answer (score 7):

Breakpoints are working fine for me when using Android Studio at `project/android/`, on both emulator and physical device. And remember to Debug instead of Run (^D instead of ^R). Note, it did **not** work when opening the project from `project/`.

---

I don't think making a new android project to write the Native code for a flutter app is a good option (vivek's suggestion). There are many Flutter specific considerations you need to make on the native side, it is not just an Android app.

Answer (score 4):

If you navigate to MainActivity.kt or MainActivity.java in the android studio then you can see "Open for Editing in Android Studio" on the top right.
click on that and it will open you a new window where you can easily write native code.

Well, better if you can write whole code in a new android project and test there then use that code to make flutter plugin. I think this will be faster than to edit in flutter project.

let me know what others think.

Comment: This is the only method I have gotten to work.  I can then attach to running app or just build from there.

Comment: According to the office Doc: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/oem-debuggers, but attaching android debug using "attach debugger to android process" does not work now, or it can use current window to switch two different debuggers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @Marcos Boaventura to follow this blog helped fix the issue. https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-app-couldnt-find-libflutter-so-c95ad81cbccd

After fixing the gradle the debug is successful. Thank you @Marcos Boaventura

Comment: I am glad for this :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. Debugging native code on an emulator worked, while debugging on a physical device (Zebra TC25, Android 7.1) crashed with a Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV). Switching from the Flutter beta channel to the Flutter stable channel fixed it for me.